# c++ calculations in the nested for loop

Tags: c++

I've been trying to do this program but I'm stuck, I'm still a beginner, any help would be appreciated. 
I need the program to do

1. Print a 10 X 10 table in which each entry in the table is the sum of the row and column number
2. Include an accumulator that will calculate the sum of all the table entries.

what I'm having a problem with is when I try to calculate the row and column for each entry and the total sum.

Each time I put any calculation in the nested for loop it messes up.  Here's with no calculations:

[image: No Calculations]

Here's with the calculations:

[image: With Calculations]

The code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    // r= row, c= column, s= sum(row+column), ts= sum of all entries   
    int r, c, s = 0, ts = 0;  
    for (r = 1; r <= 10; r++)
    {
        for (c = 1; c <= 10; c++)
        s = r + c; ** This one
        ts = ts + s; ** and this

        cout << setw(3) << c;
        cout << endl;

    }
    cout << "the total sum of all table entries is " << ts << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you want to appear in each cell of the table? The column value or the sum of the row and column?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that a loop will repeat **the next statement**. When you do it "without calculations", I assume you mean

```
for (c = 1; c <= 10; c++)
    cout << setw(3) << c;
cout << endl;
```

Here, the first `cout` statement is repeated and prints out the table in your first screenshot. (Notice the indentation here which indicates what code is "inside" the for loop.)

Now when you add the calculations, you have

```
for (c = 1; c <= 10; c++)
    s = r + c; ** This one
    ts = ts + s; ** and this
    cout << setw(3) << c;

cout << endl;
```

Even if you indent to show what you **intend** to repeat, the program will only repeat the statement immediately following the `for` loop header. In this case, you are repeating the calculation `s = r + c;` over and over. (Since this result is never used, the compiler most likely just throws it away.)

In order to repeat multiple statements, you need to wrap them in a "compound statement" which means using curly braces:

```
for (c = 1; c <= 10; c++)
{
    s = r + c; ** This one
    ts = ts + s; ** and this
    cout << setw(3) << s;
}

cout << endl;
```

I also assume that you want to print out the sum of the row and column.

I strongly suggest that you **always** use curly braces, even when you repeat a single statement. This makes it easier to add more statements inside a loop because you don't have to remember to add the curly braces later.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to enclose the inner loop in curly brackets like so:

```
for (r = 1; r <= 10; r++)
{
    for (c = 1; c <= 10; c++)
    {
    s = r + c;
    ts = ts + s;

    cout << setw(3) << c;
    cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Otherwise you will only run the

```
    s = r + c;
```

line in the inner loop.

Comment: ...and, also, indent properly.  Whatever one's philosophy on where to put braces is *(same line as the for/if/while, next line, indented with the inner code, indented with the outer code)*...you don't want the contained code at the same indentation level as the control structure.

Answer (score 1):

You need a pair of curly brackets for your for loop

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int r, c, s = 0, ts = 0;  // r= row, c= column, s= sum(row+column), ts= sum of all entries   
    for (r = 1; r <= 10; r++)
    {
        for (c = 1; c <= 10; c++) { // <- was missing
        s = r + c; ** This one
        ts = ts + s; ** and this

        cout << setw(3) << c;
        cout << endl;
        } // <- was missing

    }
    cout << "the total sum of all table entries is " << ts << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Without the `{}`, only `s = r + c` will be considered part of the for loop.

Incidentally this is the cause of the **goto fail** bugs:  http://martinfowler.com/articles/testing-culture.html